# How to use setSortBy in react-table

Tags: react-table-v7

While using the setSortBy function. It is showing the below error "setSortBy is not a function".

How im accesssing setSortBy:

const {
getTableProps,
getTableBodyProps,
headerGroups,
rows,
setSortBy,
} = useTable(
{
columns,
data,
defaultColumn,
initialState: { pageIndex: 0 },
},
usePagination,
useBlockLayout,
useResizeColumns
);

How im using:
<span onClick={() => setSortBy([{ id: column.id, desc: false }])}>
<span onClick={() => setSortBy([{ id: column.id, desc: true }])}>

Answer (score 1):

It is because, you need to include useSortBy in your useTable like this

```
const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, setSortBy, } = useTable({
 columns,
 data,
 defaultColumn,
 initialState: { pageIndex: 0 },
 },
 usePagination,
 useBlockLayout,
 useResizeColumns,
 useSortBy
 );
```

without including this useSortBy, you cannot able to destructure setSortBy from useTable